# Error on tooltip for "convert to wiki" mod tools option

Tags: bug, status-completed, tooltips, moderator-tools

I've just spotted that the tooltip for the "convert to wiki" is wrong. It reads:

> converts this post and all questions to community wiki mode

It should read

> converts this post and all answers to community wiki mode

Or something along those lines.

Evidence:

[image: shome mishtake shurely]
<sub>(source: [free-online.co.uk](http://www.forman.free-online.co.uk/images/tooltip-error.png))</sub>

This is on both Programmers and Web Applications.

**UPDATE**

Is this being looked at all?

Comment: Man... I'd be scared to click that...

Comment: @Shog9 - it made me stop and think for a while!

Comment: If that's on a question, then maybe "converts this **question** and all ...". Do you have an option of converting a specific answer to CW? If so, what does that tooltip say?

Comment: @Jon - there's no option on an answer - you've just got to go in and edit it.

Comment: Thanks btw for CWing all the answers on that question.

Comment: @TheLQ - it would have gone automatically if one more answer had been added, but that didn't look like it was going to happen...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has now been fixed with the new mod tools dialog:

[image]

The tooltip has been replaced by "in dialog" text.

Comment: That looks a lot nicer.